# LotusScript : Sending data via the POST method HTTP

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I want to send data to a server with a POST request.
In my case, I have an agent that will retrieve the information from the open email to send this data to the servers. But for the data transmission (HTTP POST), I need to provide data in JSON format in params.

However I have not found anywhere clear information on how to create a JSON with data. I can easily retrieve the data from the email but I don't know how to convert it to JSON. Is it possible to do this easily? Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Depend on your Version. There are classes for that since Version 10: NotesJSONObject, NotesJSONArray, NotesJSONNavigator, ...

Comment: Yes, I've already looked at that. But my concern is that I can't find any examples of how to use them. I can't find how to fill in a JSON expression. All I have found is how to retrieve data in JSON (GetFirstElement, GetElementByName, etc.). But i want to make something like that: json.add("lastname", "Richards"). Is it possible? Thank you for your advice

Comment: JSON is a simple text format, that one can build by himself. But of course this has been done before. As unfortunately the default classes do not support construction of JSON just reading I usually use the classes from [OpenNTF](https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/JSON%20LotusScript%20Classes). They contains help and examples on how to build valid JSON. And sending the json was shown by Per Henrik.

Comment: I use https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/JSON%20LS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This simple example should help you.

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim url As String
Dim jsonBody As String

url="https://example.com"
jsonBody="{'param 1:'value 1'}"

Dim http As NotesHTTPRequest
Set http=session.CreateHTTPRequest()

Call http.SetHeaderField("ContentType","application/json")
Call http.Post(url,jsonBody)
```

The json content in the example is built using a string called jsonBody. Here's an example where you build the string using other variables:

```
Dim lastname As String
lastname="Richards"
jsonBody="{'param 1':'" + lastname + "'}";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What can I do if now I want to edit the value of "param 1" afterwards? (but before sending the data)

Comment: Or if i want make something like that:
Dim lastname As String;
lastname="Richards";
jsonBody=|{"param 1": lastname}|;

Comment: I updated my answer and changed to using " instead of | as string quotes.